# Existing orders with deleted coupon throw EntityMetadataWrapperException

Tags: 7

My users have been placing orders on my website with a coupon code that now no longer exists. Any orders that previously used the coupon/discount 'freeshipping' are now throwing me the following error when I try to edit them (change their status):

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Missing data values. in
>   EntityMetadataWrapper->value() (line 83 of
>   /sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc)

Is there any way to fix this? I need to be able to edit those orders and change their status from pending to processing. I had a look at [this discussion](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_coupon/issues/2818607), but it doesn't seem like a solid solution was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If time is a factor you could just create a new coupon that matches the machine name of the old one.

Then when you are ready to fix them, first edit the orders to remove the coupons from them.once all are removed, then delete the coupon.